# Submit JSON data in Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a web app where a list of options are displayed dynamically in a table.  Each table row has some text, and a submit button.  I am having trouble passing the JSON data from that specific table row to my backend route when clicking submit. Here is a simplified example:

```
div.AnimalsTable
    table(style='width:100%;background-color:white', border='1')
        tr
          th Animals
        each animalType in typesOfAnimals
          each animal in animalType
            tr
              td
                form(method="POST" action="/animals/selection")
                  div.AnimalName
                    p #{animal.name}
                  div.SelectAnimalButton
                    button(class="btn btn-small" type="submit" value=animal) Select Animal
                  div.AnimalInfo
                    p #{animal.age}, #{animal.city}
```

This works fine for firing a request to my `POST /animals/selection` endpoint, but in it the request body is empty.  How can I actually submit the animal json to my endpoint?

Comment: Forms don't submit data in JSON format, they use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. If you're using Express, you need to use the `express.urlencoded()` middleware for the incoming form data to appear as the request body.

Comment: @rav2040 I am using that middleware, `req.body` is an empty object.  So is `req.query` for that matter

Comment: I missed it the first time but it also looks like your form doesn't actually have any input fields. You need HTML input fields that have values for the form to submit, as putting the values in `div` or `p` tags will have no effect on what gets submitted. You can use hidden input types for this purpose, i.e. `input(type="hidden" name="animalName" value=animal.name)`

Comment: @rav2040 That seemed to do the trick, thank you!